# How should I update "import {Http , Response} from @angular/http" module to Angular 6?

Tags: angular, module, nativescript, httpclient, updates

I have a code like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl'; 
import { ProcessHTTPMsgService } from './process-httpmsg.service'; 
import {map, delay, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators'; 


@Injectable() export class DishService {

    constructor(public http: Http, 
        private processHTTPMsgService: ProcessHTTPMsgService) { }

    getDishes(): Observable<Dish[]> { 
        return this.http.get(baseURL + 'dishes')
        .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData (res); }) 
        ,catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService .handleError(error); })); 
    }

    getDish(id: number): Observable<Dish> { 
        return this.http.get(baseURL + 'dishes/'+ id) 
        .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData (res); }) 
        ,catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService .handleError(error); }));
    }

    getFeaturedDish(): Observable<Dish> { 
        return this.http.get(baseURL + 'dishes?featured=true') 
        .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData (res)[0]; }) 
        ,catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService .handleError(error); })); 
    }
}
```

That I think the `Http` and 'Response`modules are deprecated and should be replaced by`httpClient`and maybe`HttpResponse`, but also I think I must do other modifications inside the code. So as I am a new learner I don't really know how to do that and am here to get your experienced professionals help.

When I run the program I get this error message:

```
Error:200 - "originalStack":"Error.java.io.IOException:Cleartext -
```

In the emulator's screen.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you only need change from `Http` to `HttpClient` in `constructor` and no need update code inside

```
@Injectable() export class DishService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient, 
        private processHTTPMsgService: ProcessHTTPMsgService) { }

    getDishes(): Observable<Dish[]> { 
        return this.http.get(baseURL + 'dishes')
        .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData (res); }) 
        ,catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService .handleError(error); })); 
    }

    getDish(id: number): Observable<Dish> { 
        return this.http.get(baseURL + 'dishes/'+ id) 
        .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData (res); }) 
        ,catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService .handleError(error); }));
    }

    getFeaturedDish(): Observable<Dish> { 
        return this.http.get(baseURL + 'dishes?featured=true') 
        .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData (res)[0]; }) 
        ,catchError(error => { return this.processHTTPMsgService .handleError(error); })); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I think I had a mistake in my question, I must change `http` to `httpClientModule` I think, isn't it?

Comment: I also like to know what should I do about the imported `Response` module? It seems it's unusable in the program.

Comment: you can remove it and use import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

Comment: Doesn't work. Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Response'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': headers, ok, redirected, status, and 12 more.ts(2345)

Comment: It gives the above error with the lines that have `(res)` like this line `        .pipe(map(res => { return this.processHTTPMsgService.extractData (res); }) `